# Ruby - URL to Markdown

Tags: ruby, markdown

TOTAL rookie here.

I'm working on customizing a script made by Brett Terpstra - http://brettterpstra.com/2013/11/01/save-pocket-favorites-to-nvalt-with-ifttt-and-hazel/

Mine is a different use: I'd like to save my pinboard bookmarks with a specific tag to a file in dropbox in Markdown.

I feed it a text file such as:

```
Title: Yesterday is over.
URL: http://www.jonacuff.com/blog/want-to-change-the-world-get-doing/
Tags: 2md, 2wcx, 2pdf
Date: June 20, 2013 at 06:20PM
Image: notused
Excerpt: You can't start the next chapter of your life if you keep re-reading the last one.
```

And it outputs the markdown file.

Everything works great except when the 'excerpt' (see above) is more than one line. Sometimes it's a couple of paragraphs. When that happens, it stops working. When I hit enter from the command line, it's still waiting for more input.

Here's an example of a file that it doesn't work on:

```
Title: Talking ’bout my Generation.
URL: http://blog.greglaurie.com/?p=8881
Tags: 2md, 2wcx, 2pdf
Date: June 28, 2013 at 09:46PM
Image: notused
Excerpt: Contrast two men from the 19th century: Max Jukes and Jonathan Edwards.

Max Jukes lived in New York. He did not believe in Christ or in raising his children in the way of the Lord. He refused to take his children to church, even when they asked to go. Of his 1,026 descendants:
•300 were sent to prison for an average term of 13 years
•190 were prostitutes
•680 were admitted alcoholics
His family, thus far, has cost the state in excess of $420,000 and has made no contribution to society.

Jonathan Edwards also lived in New York, at the same time as Jukes. He was known to have studied 13 hours a day and, in spite of his busy schedule of writing, teaching, and pastoring, he made it a habit to come home and spend an hour each day with his children. He also saw to it that his children were in church every Sunday. Of his 929 descendants:
•430 were ministers
•86 became university professors
•13 became university presidents
•75 authored good books
•7 were elected to the United States Congress
•1 was Vice President of the United States
Edwards’ family never cost the state one cent.

We tend to think that our decisions only affect ourselves, but they have ramifications for generations to come.
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like after I run the command: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9zg483k7nkdp6f/Screenshot%202013-11-22%2016.39.17.png
I'm hoping it's something easy. Any ideas?

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Works with IFTTT recipe https://ifttt.com/recipes/125999
#
# Set Hazel to watch the folder you specify in the recipe.
# Make sure nvALT is set to store its notes as individual files.
# Edit the $target_folder variable below to point to your nvALT
# ntoes folder.
require 'date'
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'fileutils'
require 'cgi'

$target_folder = "~/Dropbox/messx/urls2md"

def url_to_markdown(url)
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://heckyesmarkdown.com/go/"),{'u'=>url,'read'=>'1'})
    if res.code.to_i == 200
        res.body
    else
        false
    end
end

file = ARGV[0]

begin
    input = IO.read(file).force_encoding('utf-8')

    headers = {}
    input.each_line {|line|
        key, value = line.split(/: /)
        headers[key] = value.strip || ""
    }

    outfile = File.join(File.expand_path($target_folder), headers['Title'].gsub(/["!*?'|]/,'') + ".txt")

    date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    date_added = Date.parse(headers['Date']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    content = "Title: #{headers['Title']}\nDate: #{date}\nDate Added: #{date_added}\nSource: #{headers['URL']}\n"

    tags = false
    if headers['Tags'].length > 0
        tag_arr = header    s['Tags'].split(", ")
        tag_arr.map! {|tag|
            %Q{"#{tag.strip}"}
        }
        tags = tag_arr.join(" ")
        content += "Keywords: #{tags}\n"
    end

    markdown = url_to_markdown(headers['URL']).force_encoding('utf-8')

    if markdown
        content += headers['Image'].length > 0 ? "\n\n> #{headers['Excerpt']}\n\n---#{markdown}\n" : "\n\n"+markdown
    else
        content += headers['Image'].length > 0 ? "\n\n![](#{headers['Image']})\n\n#{headers['Excerpt']}\n" : "\n\n"+headers['Excerpt']
    end

    File.open(outfile,'w') {|f|
        f.puts content
    }

    if tags && File.exists?("/usr/local/bin/openmeta")
        %x{/usr/local/bin/openmeta -a #{tags} -p "#{outfile}"}
    end
    # FileUtils.rm(file)
rescue Exception => e
    puts e
end
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input file that breaks it?  I added an extra "Excerpt:" line, and it completes.  The way you've coded it, it blows away the previous "Excerpt:" line, but it doesn't hang.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just added an example file and a screenshot of what it looks like when I try to run it.

Comment: I guess the problem is not with the length of the excerpt. Rather the problem is _the colon_ there in the excerpt. Try to surround your text with single quotes and everything will likely be fine.

Comment: Cool I'll try that. Should I surround the excerpt with single quotes in the input file or in the ruby script, or where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?  Modify your `input.each_line` area accordingly:

```
headers = {}
key = nil
input.each_line do |line|
  match = /^(?<key>\w+)\s*:\s*(?<value>.*)/.match(line)
  value = line
  if match
    key = match[:key].strip
    headers[key] = match[:value].strip
  else
    headers[key] += line
  end
end
```

First, splitting on just ":" is dangerous since that can be in content.  Instead, a (simplified from code) regex of `/^\w+:.*/` will match "Word: Content".  Since the lines after the "Excerpt:" aren't prefixed, you need to hang on to the last seen key, and just append if there's no key for this line.  You may need to add a newline in there, depending on what you're doing with that header information, but it seems to work.

Comment: Yes!!! That's working! Although I've encountered a different error. Not sure if it's related. If the 'title' field has a slash (EG: Title: This Weekend at Harvest/Riverside and Orange County.) it errors out again like this: (screenshot) https://www.dropbox.com/s/fou21inpvfv6vsp/Screenshot%202013-11-23%2019.18.44.png - Thanks again for your help, I still have so much to learn! :)

Comment: You'll need to alter your `headers['Title'].gsub(/["!*?'|]/,'') + ".txt"` to also remove the `/` character.

Comment: `headers['Title'].gsub(/["!*?'|\/\\]/,'') + ".txt")` - Works perfectly! Thanks so much again Nick!